# Question about the letters in the Mandylion Icon

Tags: eastern-orthodox, greek, iconography

I am trying to determine what language the letters around Christ's head in the Mandylion Icon are written in and what they are equivalent to in English.

[image]

[image]

I think in the Icon above, they are ancient Greek and say "I AM", but can't seem to verify this.

Thanks in advance..
God Bless.

Comment: Duplicate:
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83217/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-three-letters-in-the-halo-of-the-acheiropoieta